# Xdmx: Fatal server error, could not open default font 'fixed'

Tags: xorg, xdmx

I followed this video to use another laptop as a second monitor/screen.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOzRCBGDVaE

the basic idea is: if I have two laptops with linux: my main laptop and the second laptop. I installed Xdmx on both laptops. Then I ssh into my main laptop from the second laptop, and then run command under the ssh session:

```
startx -- /usr/bin/Xdmx :1 +xinerama -display :0.0 -display localhost:10.0 -norender -noglxproxy
```

when I run the command

```
startx -- /usr/bin/Xdmx :1 +xinerama -display :0.0 -display localhost:10.0 -norender -noglxproxy
```

I got a fatal error, how to deal with it?

```
    I) dmx: Generation:         1
    (II) dmx: DMX version:        1.2.20070424 (DMX Project)
    (II) dmx: DMX Build OS:       Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 (Ubuntu)
    (II) dmx: DMX Build Compiler: gcc 4.8.2
    (II) dmx: DMX Execution OS:   Linux 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
    (II) dmx: DMX Execution Host: mypad
    (II) dmx: MAXSCREENS:         16
    (II) dmx: Using configuration from command line
    (II) dmx: Added :0.0 at 0 0
    (II) dmx: Added localhost:11.0 right of :0.0
    (II) dmx[o0/:0.0]: No Xdmx server running on backend
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Name of display: localhost:11.0
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Version number:  11.0
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Vendor string:   Fedora Project
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Vendor release:  11303000
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Dimensions:      1366x768 pixels
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 7 depths on screen 0:  24,1,4,8,15,16,32
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Depth of root window:  24 planes (24)
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Number of colormaps:   1 min, 1 max
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Options: backing-store no, save-unders no
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Window Manager running: yes
    (**) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: Window manager running -- colormaps not supported
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 1366x768+0+0 on 1366x768 at depth=24, bpp=32
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x21 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff *
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x22 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x7a TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x7b TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x7c TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x7d TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x7e DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x7f DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x80 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x81 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x82 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: 0x61 TrueColor   32b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
    Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
    Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
    Initializing built-in extension XTEST
    Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
    Initializing built-in extension SYNC
    Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
    Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
    Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
    Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
    Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
    Initializing built-in extension RENDER
    Initializing built-in extension RECORD
    Initializing built-in extension DPMS
    Initializing built-in extension Present
    Initializing built-in extension DRI3
    Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
    Initializing built-in extension SELinux
    Initializing built-in extension DMX
    Initializing built-in extension GLX
    (II) dmx[o0/:0.0]: DPMS 1.1 (on, enabled, 0 0 0)
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: DPMS 1.1 (on, enabled, 0 0 0)
    (II) dmx[o0/:0.0]: (request) s=1366x768+0+0 r=1366x768+0+0 @0,0 (0) (be=1366x768 depth=24 bpp=32)
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: (request) s=1366x768+0+0 r=1366x768+0+0 @0,0 (1) (be=1366x768 depth=24 bpp=32)
    (II) dmx[o0/:0.0]: s=1366x768+0+0 r=1366x768+0+0 @0,0 (be=1366x768 depth=24 bpp=32)
    (II) dmx[o1/localhost:11.0]: s=1366x768+0+0 r=1366x768+0+0 @1366,0 (be=1366x768 depth=24 bpp=32)
    (II) dmx: Using 2732x768 as global bounding box
    (II) dmx: XSync batching with 100 ms interval
    [dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic, removing from list!
    [dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled, removing from list!
    [dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled, removing from list!
    [dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi, removing from list!
    [dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi, removing from list!
    (**) dmx: No default font path is set.
    (!!) dmx: The DMX server failed to set the following font paths on screen #1:
    (!!) dmx:     /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc
    (!!) dmx:     /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1
    (!!) dmx: Please specify the font paths that are available on all back-end
    (!!) dmx: servers with the "-fontpath" option, or use the "-ignorebadfontpaths"
    (!!) dmx: to ignore bad defaults.  For more information on these and other
    (!!) dmx: font-path-related options, see the Xdmx man page.
    (EE)
    Fatal server error:
    (EE) could not open default font 'fixed'(EE)
```

I tried to add `-ignorebadfontpaths`, but then the two screens became black.

Comment: No session manager?

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?